# Drawing sprites messes up my model in XNA4

Tags: graphics-programming, state, depth-buffer, blending, xna-4.0

I have a model which draws correctly in XNA4.

However if I try to add a background image (or any sprite), the rendering of my model is messed up. There are two problems with the rendering

1. model is partially transparent
2. hidden surfaces are visible.

[image: This is the 'problem' rendering] Above is the 'problem' rendering (the cyan coloured cockpit cover is visible through the bottom of the ship)

[image: This is how the rendering *should* look] This is how the rendering *should* look

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by the SpriteBatch.Begin() changing some of the rendering states.

This problem is solved in XNA 3.1 and earlier by using the SaveState flag (see this [answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/41927/4568)).

However in XNA 4.0+ you need to restore the state yourself.

Insert the following code *after* your sprite drawing but *before* your model drawing (or 3D primitive drawing)

```
GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```

Information based on [original article by Shawn Hargreaves](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)